# How to display a specific line at the top of a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm pulling the content from a text file into a RichTextBox.  I've got the RichTextBox set up to where it only shows 6 lines at a time.  I've got a search method that finds the text I need within the RichTextBox, but what I am needing it to do is display 6 specific lines.  Each "item" in my text file consists of 6 lines.  No matter which of the six lines the search method finds the text on, I need the RichTextBox to only display the 6 lines of each "item" with the currently selected "found" text remaining highlighted.

I've gotten it working reasonably well thanks to a few code examples I've pull from this site.  But every now and then, it doesn't work entirely well, and am looking for some advice from a fresh set of eyes looking at my code and perhaps even be told an easier/more efficient way to go about it.  But here is my code so far.  Thanks in advance!

```
try
        {
            string s = txtFindPlaylistEntry.Text;
            rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Focus();
            findPosEntry = rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Find(s, findPosEntry, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

            // Jump to the line we need.
            int count = rtxEditPlaylistEntry.GetLineFromCharIndex(findPosEntry);
            count = (count - (count % 6)) + 1; // Must be divisible by 6 then plus 1
            rtxEditPlaylistEntry.SelectionStart = rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Find(rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Lines[count]);
            rtxEditPlaylistEntry.ScrollToCaret();

            rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Select(findPosEntry, s.Length);
            findPosEntry += txtFindPlaylistEntry.Text.Length;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No occurences found");
            findPosEntry = 0;
        }
```

As of right now, I'm attempting to use a line count with modulus plus 1 to get the line I need.  Like I said, it works, just not 100% of the time and I can't figure out why.

EDIT to try to accommodate Minimal, Complete, Verifiable.

I've already posted my "find" function.  Here is other related code that might be useful.  First, here is my code for creating the various controls I am using.

```
rtxEditPlaylistEntry = new RichTextBox();
        rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 90);
        rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(375, 85);
        rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Multiline = true;
        rtxEditPlaylistEntry.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
```

Here is my button function to pull text from a file and place it into the RichTextBox.

```
private void btnBrowseForPlaylistToEditEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "LPL Files|*.lpl";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            savedFileNameEntry = openFileDialog.SafeFileName;
            txtPathToPlaylistToEditEntry.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }

        // After finding the file, load it into the richtextbox control
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFileDialog.FileName))
        {
            // Initially show the first 6 lines (IE first entry).  This should be accomplished by
            // the richtextbox control settings
            rtxEditPlaylistEntry.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        previousNextCount = 0;
    }
```

I hope this is sufficient.  If not please let me know!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you mean by your code not working all of the time? What is the behaviour you are experiencing when it breaks?

Comment: Most of the time, it will work like it is supposed to.  But if I try to search for the string "sf", it will work, then it will be "off" for the next few that it finds.  It still correctly finds "sf", but it doesn't place the line I want at the top of the richtextbox.  If I continue with finding the next "sf" instances, it will eventually correct itself.  If I repeat the "sf" search, it will go "off" at the same spot every time.  So far, that is the only string that throws it off.  I haven't found any others that give me problems.  But I'm still testing :).

Comment: OK that sounds kinda like a race condition to me, but without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's a little hard to know for sure. Can you update your example as per the help article?

Comment: Ok.  I'll try to gather the pertinent info.  This is my first question on this site and still getting a feel for how things work :).